# Как найти определенный символ в строке и удалить значение после него (и вместе с ним) Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, есть определенный набор строк, типа `"L / Красный / 12345"`, как можно на странице найти их, и вырезать из них все что находится после символа `"/"` (и вместе с ним). строки разные, нужно что бы в каждом из них оставались нетронутыми символы до этого знака. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr = str.split('/'),
    changeStr = arr[0] || '';
```

можно регуляркой

```
str.match(/([^\/]*)/)
```